# indexes for group by on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, group-by

I have a large temp table (~160 million rows) `#itemsTemp`

```
itemId  | style    | styleWeight
--------------------------------
int     | smallint | float(53)
```

and the following query on it:

```
select 
    itemId,
    style,
    SUM(styleWeight) itemCount 
from 
    #itemsTemp 
group by itemId,style
```

Currently `#itemsTemp` has no indexes. I'm a little confused about what would be best here:

1. A composite index on `itemId` and `style` (and probably `include` styleWeight)
2. Separate indexes on `itemId` and `style`

Which way should I go? Why? Any other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composite index on `itemId` and `style` with `styleWeight` included would be the best option.

This will allow `Stream Aggregate` without sorting and/or clustered seek/RID lookup overhead.

Comment: Super. After building the index (~10min operation) the query completes in about a minute. This is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2008 actually [suggests missing indexes if you include the actual execution plan](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/12/29/SQL-Server-Management-Studio-2008-suggests-missing-indexes-with-actual.aspx).  The [database tuning advisor tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173494.aspx) also suggests indexes for you.

However **the optimal indexes depends on the other queries run against this table**:

- Evert index you add to a table has both a storage penalty and a performance penalty when writing, and so if you write to this table you want to keep the number of indexes reasonably low in order to keep write performance acceptable.
- If many other queries use the same 2 columns then you may want to use a composite index as long as those queries can all take advantage of that index (remember that the order of a composite index matters).
- Conversely if other queries cannot take advantage of a composite index it may be better to use two separate indexes - the performance may be lower for this query however this could be worth it overall if the index re-use reduces the number of indexes on this table.

In reality the index suggestion feature tends to work pretty well - I usully just do what it suggests (after a quick think / sanity check) and then just run some simple tests to make sure that the query is actually performing with the new index(es).

Comment: Sure, but running the query without indexes would take **a little while** (read as: a rather long time!). The table is temporary (from a previous `select bla into #itemsTemp`), so the inserts are performed while it has no indexes to. It exists solely for the purpose of the query in my question and will subsequently be dropped, so I don't need to consider any other usage scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from evaluating the performance both ways (manually), you can use query optimizing hints -- for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx.

Also -- if your temp table is so big, I wonder if there isn't a better way to solve the problem than using a temp table.

Also -- how often are you writing versus reading?  How long is the session?  Are you making it available to other procedures?

Comment: I've tried using CTEs to solve this, but the volume of data means I run out of memory pretty quickly, so I've had to resort to temp tables. As this is a process that will only be run every couple of months on a dedicated machine, temp tables are fine.